# Notifications without internet

Tags: android, kotlin

Im working on app in android studio, but I get some technical problem.
My app is working on like 15 devices in Wi-Fi network without Internet access, just taking some data from MySQL database. Is it possible to add some notifications when there is new record in database?

I just dont know what to do, its out of my brain. I searched some forums but I cannot get how to connect notifications with new record in database.

Comment: Welcome to SO ☺ It might be helpful to explain a bit more what you mean by "in Wi-Fi network without Internet access"? Is your database on your local network that your devices are connecting to?